# How to convert a variable to UUID if not yet a UUID (otherwise, no-op)

Tags: python, casting

I'm trying to compare a variable that I know is a UUID to a variable that may be a str or may already be a UUID - if the type-unsure variable is a str, the comparison does not work properly. I'd like to force the variable to be a UUID without getting all verbose with instance of

So, this code always throw exceptions if `uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid` is a str at runtime - is there a way to force the type of `uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid` to UUID?

```
if for_sure_a_uuid != uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid:
    raise Exception("not the right UUID")
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work if `uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid` is a `UUID` already - the constructor throws an error as its trying to treat it as an str

```
if for_sure_a_uuid != uuid.UUID(uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid):
    raise Exception("not the right UUID")
```

Comment: Why are you against calling `isinstance()` once?  That seems like the right solution.

Comment: "instance of"? you mean `isinstance()`, right?

Comment: Define your own little function that does the `isinstance` check and guaranteed returns a `UUID`…‽ `if ensure_uuid(uuid_as_an_str_or_uuid) …`

Comment: so y'all are saying there is no built in way to ensure a variable is a uuid - it's roll your own?
Also, what's up with equality/inequality operators silently comparing disparate types in python and acting tautologically when they do? Not being able to compare a UUID that's a str with a UUID that's a UUID sure seems to go against the "any object that behaves as a duck should be treated as a duck" philosphy

Comment: That's not really what duck typing is about. Arguably a string *is not equal to an instance of UUID*, even if their values express the same thing. Python values being explicit over implicit magic; considering them equal would entail some implicit conversions, which would go against this idea. But consider it the other way around: `str` will cast a `UUID` to a string and will be a noop on a string; is that what you want…?

Comment: @deceze that does work, except now you're doing a string compare which is definitely less efficient then a 128 UUID compare
It would be nice if python's UUID had something built in that was like `int` where you can put either a string or int into it and it spits out an int

ie, `12 == int(int_var)` works, and so does `12 == int(str_var)`